# Gatsby dynamic routing breaks upon gh-pages deploy

Tags: deployment, gatsby, github-pages, reach-router, dynamic-routing

I deployed my first Gatsby project to github pages:
repo: https://github.com/michal-kurz/stfuandclick
gh-pages: https://michal-kurz.github.io/stfuandclick/app/ (generated from `gh-pages` branch)

It has one page, `src/pages/app.tsx`, which uses use [Reach Router](https://reach.tech/router/) for dynamic routing.

```
// app.tsx
const App = () => (
  <>
    <GlobalStyles />
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Router>
          <Homepage path={`${BASE_URL}/app/`} />
          <Team path={`${BASE_URL}/app/team/:teamName/`} />
        </Router>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Provider>
  </>
)
```

```js
// gatsby-node.js
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  if (page.path.match(/^\/app/)) {
    page.matchPath = '/app/*'
    createPage(page)
  }
}
```

**note**: `BASE_URL` equals to `/stfuandclick` in production env version and `''` in other envs

Everything works fine in development mode (`gatsby develop`), but on the deployed version, it is impossible to visit `/team/:teamName` without using `/app/` as the app's entry point (going to `/app/` and click the blue button works fine).

Opening the [/team/:teamName](https://michal-kurz.github.io/stfuandclick/app/team/test) link directly results in a 404 (unless previously cached by visiting it through `/app/`, but then ctrl + f5 results in 404 again).

At seems as if `gatsby.node.js` isn't doing it's job properly once app is deployed. I initialy suspected that it does't work at all, but apparently that's not the case, as commenting all the code out breaks the app even further (the team pages suddenly break even upon visited via link from `/app`).

I tried prefixing the paths in `gatsby-node.js` with `BASE_URL` in the production build like so:

```js
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  if (page.path.match(/^\/stfuandclick\/app/)) {
    page.matchPath = '/stfuandclick/app/*'
    createPage(page)
  }
}
```

and also prefixing each of the two paths in `gatsby-node.js` individually, but with no luck.

I do have `pathPrefix` in my `gatsby-config.json`: ([full config here](https://github.com/michal-kurz/stfuandclick/blob/master/gatsby-config.js))

```
module.exports = {
  pathPrefix: '/stfuandclick',
  // ...
}
```

and I deploy with the following yarn script: ([full package.json here](https://github.com/michal-kurz/stfuandclick/blob/master/package.json))

```
"deploy": "gatsby build --prefix-paths && gh-pages -d public"
```

What can I do to make my routing work?

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue while working on [vickywords](https://vickywords.com/). I hosted my site on Vercel. Basically, the server is trying to locate the document by path `dynamic-route/param/` and it is not aware of dynamic routes. So it is throwing a 404 error.

To fix that, I had to make 2 changes in my source code.

1. In the 404.js file I made the below changes to get rid of 404 flashing. In my case, I was seeing a 404 error in the browser console. [source](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/5329)

`const browser = typeof window !== "undefined" && window;`

`return browser && <NotFoundPage />;`

2. In vercel.json file I had to add redirects to the root page like below.

`{ "rewrites": [{ "source": "/word-finder/(.*)", "destination": "/word-finder" }] }`

There is one issue I noticed, [word-finder](https://vickywords.com/word-finder/) page is the root page for my dynamic route with some text. When a user searches for something, I simply redirect to the same page with parameters that will render dynamic content. I see the flashing of my root page with text before seeing the actual content.
I believe it is due to that URL redirect.

Note:
If anyone is using Netlify, they can add the same behavior in the `_redirect` file. Make sure to put it in the `static` folder so that it will get copied after deployment.

Comment: Ok, that sound promissing, I'll try to figure out a gh-pages analogy to that when I can get to it. Thanks!

Comment: So I tried to deploy to Netlify instead, but I got an odd but somwehat similar problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65081032/gatsby-spa-deployed-on-netlify-applies-wrong-emotion-css-on-first-load-distille

Comment: I guess it is analogous to your 404 flashing, just with `app.tsx` instead and combined with an emotionjs quirk. Did you perhaps manage to stumble upon a good solution to the flashing problem?

Comment: I am not seeing 404 flashing after applying the solution which I mentioned in my answer.

That CSS/emotion-js, even I faced that too with material UI components. As a workaround, I used SCSS for effect components. This issue I noticed only on dynamic pages.

Comment: I have migrated the app to `next.js`, it has SSR and Vercel supports it via Serverless functions. GatsbyJS is good but it is not a good fit for my project.